# Random Binary Tree in Dart

Tags: dart, binary-tree

I need to generate random binary trees given only the number of nodes. I want to do it with a linked tree structure with classes. Is it possible? Or is there another way? I couldn't find any resources on this. I suppose a java-like example could work as well.

Comment: You can simply generate N random numbers. Then you insert them in the tree.

Comment: Btw, what does this have to do with Dart?

Comment: The shape of the tree should be random. So it is not as easy as generating N random numbers. And since I just got into Dart, it may have some features which could help me in this case that I don't know yet. But an experienced person in Dart might know.

Comment: If the tree data structure you are using is not self-balancing (but even if it's self-balancing), generating N random numbers and inserting them in the tree is sufficient to generate a tree with a random shape.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. How are you guaranteeing that every node in the tree will be connected? Couldn't there be possible disconnected sub-trees?

Comment: Why would the tree be disconnected?

Comment: I think I don't understand your method then. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of different ways you might do this. Here's one possible way. It creates the nodes and then connects them by walking through each one and giving it a random parent from the nodes with open spots.

```
import 'dart:math';

const maxNodes = 10;

void main() {
  final rng = Random();
  final nodes = List.generate(maxNodes, (index) => Node(index + 1));
  final openNodes = [nodes[0]];
  nodes.skip(1).forEach((node) {
    node.parent = openNodes[rng.nextInt(openNodes.length)];
    openNodes.add(node);
    if (node.parent.right != null ||
        (node.parent.left == null && rng.nextBool())) {
      node.parent.left = node;
    } else
      node.parent.right = node;
    if (node.parent.left != null && node.parent.right != null)
      openNodes.remove(node.parent);
  });
  nodes.forEach(print);
}

class Node {
  Node(this.id);
  final int id;
  Node parent;
  Node left;
  Node right;
  @override
  String toString() => '$id: (${left?.id ?? '_'}, ${right?.id ?? '_'})';
}
```

Test it out on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/275d38e827bbaead27ff68f8e3f2c660).

Comment: Thanks for the method. But since next can only be either left or right in each iteration (if not current), doesn't this mean we're only going down one path? For example, if we choose to go left from the root, the right side of the tree will have no possibility to grow, I think?

Comment: I never thought of building the tree from the bottom up. This seems to be working well. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's top down. Starts at the root and fills in open spots randomly.

Comment: True. I meant bottom up as in assigning random parents first, rather than assigning children. It was the wrong term to use I suppose.